# Javascript - Filter array results into dropdown list

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have an array as shown below where I want to filter the data and insert the filtered list into a dropdown list.

Here is the data:

```
{"people":[
    {
      "id":"100",
      "name":"name 1",
      "desc":"desc 1",
      "class": "a"
    },
    {
      "id":"192",
      "name":"name 2",
      "desc":"desc 2",
      "class": "b" 
    },
    {
      "id":"324",
      "name":"name 3",
      "desc":"desc 3",
      "class": "b" 
    },
    {
      "id":"324",
      "name":"name 4",
      "desc":"desc 4",
      "class": "a" 
    },
    {
      "id":"324",
      "name":"name 5",
      "desc":"desc 5",
      "class": "a"
    }
]}
```

What I now need to do is to add the array with "class" of "a" and then insert the id's of these into a dropdown list like:

```
$('#myselect').append($('<option>').text(value.id).attr('value', value.id));
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Can you mention the expected output array ? do you want to filter the records with `class="a"`

Comment: Yes exactly...I want to filter the records with class="a"

Comment: for (var i = 0; i < value.people.length; i++) {
            if(value.people[i].class == "a")
            {
                $('#myselect').append($('<option value="' + value.people[i].id + '">' + value.people[i].id + '</option>'));

            }
        }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an solution using [`Array.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

```js
var obj = {
  "people": [{
    "id": "100",
    "name": "name 1",
    "desc": "desc 1",
    "class": "a"
  }, {
    "id": "192",
    "name": "name 2",
    "desc": "desc 2",
    "class": "b"
  }, {
    "id": "324",
    "name": "name 3",
    "desc": "desc 3",
    "class": "b"
  }, {
    "id": "324",
    "name": "name 4",
    "desc": "desc 4",
    "class": "a"
  }, {
    "id": "324",
    "name": "name 5",
    "desc": "desc 5",
    "class": "a"
  }]
};

obj.people.filter(function(val) {
  if (val.class == "a") {
    $('#myselect').append($('<option>').text(val.id).attr('value', val.id));
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="myselect">
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this with [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/4.16.0) library

```
//Filter with class = 'a'
var peopleWithClassA = _.filter(obj.people, { class: 'a' });

//Append option elem for each filtered people
_.forEach(peopleWithClassA, function(people) {
   $('#myselect').append($('<option>')
                 .text(people.id)
                 .attr('value', people.id));
});
```

Without lodash :

```
obj.people
.filter(function(p) {
    return p.class === 'a';
})
.forEach(function(p) {
    $('#myselect').append($('<option>').text(p.id).attr('value', p.id));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

#### Logic

- Get unique class names.
- Loop on this unique values and filter data based on it
- Create htmlString based on object and append it to necessary select

If you feel, adding `select`s in html is an over kill, you can generate them also based on data.

#### Sample

```js
var data = {
  "people": [{
    "id": "100",
    "name": "name 1",
    "desc": "desc 1",
    "class": "a"
  }, {
    "id": "192",
    "name": "name 2",
    "desc": "desc 2",
    "class": "b"
  }, {
    "id": "324",
    "name": "name 3",
    "desc": "desc 3",
    "class": "b"
  }, {
    "id": "324",
    "name": "name 4",
    "desc": "desc 4",
    "class": "a"
  }, {
    "id": "324",
    "name": "name 5",
    "desc": "desc 5",
    "class": "a"
  }]
}

var uniqueClasses = {};
data.people.forEach(function(p) {
  uniqueClasses[p.class] = 1;
});

Object.keys(uniqueClasses).forEach(function(c) {
  var _html = data.people.filter(function(p) {
    return p.class === c
  }).map(function(p) {
    return "<option value='" + p.id + "'>" + p.name + "</option>"
  }).join("");
  $("#class_" + c).append(_html);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="class_a"></select>
<select id="class_b"></select>
```